# How to make flexibale height for scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a scrollbar. But I want to have a flexibale height. So not static height.

I have this:

```
#roomlist {
  width: 250px;
  /* max-height: 100%; */
  max-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -210px;
  background-color: #91c7e1;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:max-content;
}
```

But now the scrollbar is not visible. But if I do this:

```
height:800px;
```

Then it is hardcoded. I want more flexibale appoach. But how to do that?

And this html:

```
   <div id="roomlist">
            <ul id="roomlistul"></ul>
        </div>
```

So this is working:

```
#roomlist {
  width: 250px;
  /* max-height: 100%; */
  max-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -210px;
  background-color: #91c7e1;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:800px;
}
```

But now height is hardcoded. What not has to be.

That is the point.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't seemed to be working as you say! can you reproduce the issue for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use height as `auto` and it will increase or decrease based on the content, you can try something like this:

```css
#roomlist {
  width: 250px;
  /* max-height: 100%; */
  max-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #91c7e1;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  /* overflow:y don't work unless you specify height! */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* specify some height so that scroll can happen when content increased */
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="roomlist">
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>
  <ul>list</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I do height: auto; I dont see the scrollbar

Comment: you will see browser scroll bar for this, if you need your custom scroll bar then you have to provide some height, its like for Ex. if you set an height of `400px` and overflow-y as scroll, then it means when the content is more than `400px` then you need a scroll, you need specify an height or at least `min-height` at least for scroll to work.

Comment: @CodeIsNice I got your issues, I just added some height and with the scroll effect, this is what I said in earlier comment.